# ActiveMQ Artemis takes too long to start when it has huge page files

Tags: activemq-artemis

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.12
- ActiveMQ Artemis: 2.25.0

My MQ has a big data as below:

```
root@mdmcs22p:~# du -h -d 1 /data/artemis/data
4.4G    /data/artemis/data/large-messages
104G    /data/artemis/data/journal
2.1M    /data/artemis/data/bindings
500G    /data/artemis/data/paging
608G    /data/artemis/data
root@mdmcs22p:~#
```

For some reason I need to restart it, so I run below command in bin folder of the broker:

```
./artemis-service restart
```

After a while, artemis dumps some exception logs. Eventually, it still completes the start action.

Does this exception matter ? And how to give Artemis more time to start JournalStorageManager without this exception ?

```
2022-09-30 06:06:30,680 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222166: No Expiry Address configured for queue mdms.lpr.kma in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,681 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222165: No Dead Letter Address configured for queue mdms.lpi.bduser in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,681 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222166: No Expiry Address configured for queue mdms.lpi.bduser in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,681 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222165: No Dead Letter Address configured for queue mdms.lpr.sadms in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,682 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222166: No Expiry Address configured for queue mdms.lpr.sadms in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,682 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222165: No Dead Letter Address configured for queue mdms.lpi.edwh in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:06:30,682 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222166: No Expiry Address configured for queue mdms.lpi.edwh in AddressSettings
2022-09-30 06:09:30,003 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalMeasure] Component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager is expired on path 0
2022-09-30 06:09:30,004 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224116: The component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager@219f4597 is not responsive during start up. The Server may be taking too long to start
2022-09-30 06:09:30,816 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222199: Thread dump: *******************************************************************************
Complete Thread dump
"main" Id=1 RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.readJournalFile(JournalImpl.java:612)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:2136)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl@36073cbf
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:2429)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl@36073cbf
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:1739)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl@36073cbf
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.Journal.load(Journal.java:278)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.loadMessageJournal(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:908)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.loadJournals(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3650)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart2(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3313)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl@5930b0c4
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:76)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:671)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:579)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl@5930b0c4
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:64)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker@3fec39f6
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:127)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:160)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:108)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:135)
        at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at app//org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134)
        at app//org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50)


"Reference Handler" Id=2 RUNNABLE
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)


"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@4d2d1b79
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@4d2d1b79
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:170)
....
....

===============================================================================
End Thread dump
*******************************************************************************

2022-09-30 06:11:42,593 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221014: 25% loaded


2022-09-30 06:11:53,330 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221014: 50% loaded
2022-09-30 06:12:01,382 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221014: 76% loaded
2022-09-30 06:12:11,906 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,907 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2022-09-30 06:12:11,912 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,912 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2022-09-30 06:12:11,913 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address IT_RECV_QUEUE supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,913 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue IT_RECV_QUEUE on address IT_RECV_QUEUE
2022-09-30 06:12:11,913 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address IT_SEND_QUEUE supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,914 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue IT_SEND_QUEUE on address IT_SEND_QUEUE
2022-09-30 06:12:11,914 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address IT_APIC_REQUEST_QUEUE supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,914 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue IT_APIC_REQUEST_QUEUE on address IT_APIC_REQUEST_QUEUE
2022-09-30 06:12:11,914 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address IT_APIC_RESPONSE_QUEUE supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,914 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue IT_APIC_RESPONSE_QUEUE on address IT_APIC_RESPONSE_QUEUE
2022-09-30 06:12:11,915 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.CustnoTransRelation.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,915 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.CustnoTransRelationTrans.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,915 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.Feeder.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,915 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.PlannedOutage.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,916 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.PlanOutageStatusChange.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,916 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.Transformer.to.MAM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,916 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address OMS.OutageRestoreQueryReply.to.STM supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,916 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STM.NonPlanOutage.to.OMS supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STM.OutageRestoreQuery.to.OMS supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STM.TransformerOutage.to.OMS supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STM.OutageRestore.to.OMS supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.all supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.all_to_ot supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,917 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.dreams supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.dreams on address mdms.lpi.dreams
2022-09-30 06:12:11,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.bduser supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.bduser on address mdms.lpi.bduser
2022-09-30 06:12:11,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.edwh supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.edwh on address mdms.lpi.edwh
2022-09-30 06:12:11,919 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.bduser2 supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,919 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.bduser2 on address mdms.lpi.bduser2
2022-09-30 06:12:11,919 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.gems supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,919 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.gems on address mdms.lpi.gems
2022-09-30 06:12:11,919 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.nbs supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,920 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.nbs on address mdms.lpi.nbs
2022-09-30 06:12:11,920 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.nbs2 supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,920 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.nbs2 on address mdms.lpi.nbs2
2022-09-30 06:12:11,920 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.daps supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,921 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.daps on address mdms.lpi.daps
2022-09-30 06:12:11,921 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.kma supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,921 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.kma on address mdms.lpi.kma
2022-09-30 06:12:11,921 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,922 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.sadms on address mdms.lpi.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,922 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.test_it supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,922 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.test_it on address mdms.lpi.test_it
2022-09-30 06:12:11,922 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.test_ot supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,923 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.test_ot on address mdms.lpi.test_ot
2022-09-30 06:12:11,923 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.amtfi supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,923 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.amtfi on address mdms.lpi.amtfi
2022-09-30 06:12:11,923 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ttu.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,923 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ttu.sadms on address ttu.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,924 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address fci.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,924 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue fci.sadms on address fci.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,924 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpi.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,924 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpi.sadms on address mdms.lpi.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,925 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.event.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,925 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.event.sadms on address mdms.event.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,925 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpr.all supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,925 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpr.kma supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,925 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpr.kma on address mdms.lpr.kma
2022-09-30 06:12:11,926 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.lpr.sadms supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,926 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue mdms.lpr.sadms on address mdms.lpr.sadms
2022-09-30 06:12:11,926 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.event.public supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,926 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.ds.LoadProfile.22.Delivered supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,926 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.ds.LoadProfile.22.Received supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,927 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.ds.MeterAssets supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,927 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address mdms.ds.MeterEvents supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,927 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address test.TestTopic supporting [MULTICAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,927 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address test.TestQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2022-09-30 06:12:11,927 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue test.TestQueue on address test.TestQueue
2022-09-30 06:12:12,241 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 192.168.11.64:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2022-09-30 06:12:12,246 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 192.168.11.64:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2022-09-30 06:12:12,250 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2022-09-30 06:12:12,251 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.25.0 [broker_1164, nodeID=f6119a4a-3fc1-11ed-9fe0-00505694e350]
2022-09-30 06:12:12,262 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2022-09-30 06:12:12,562 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2022-09-30 06:12:12,606 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2022-09-30 06:12:12,858 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2022-09-30 06:12:12,870 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2022-09-30 06:12:12,873 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.15.0
2022-09-30 06:12:12,879 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2022-09-30 06:12:12,884 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2022-09-30 06:12:12,895 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2022-09-30 06:12:12,900 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/opt/broker_1164/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2022-09-30 06:12:12,979 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: Embedded web server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2022-09-30 06:12:12,981 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2022-09-30 06:12:12,981 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
```

Comment: What's your use-case that requires having so much data on disk?

Comment: Oh, it is just an accident  that the consumer forget restarting to receive messages for 4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you have a large journal that's going to take a long time to load then this WARN message and thread dump should not be a concern. The WARN message is emitted by the [critical analyzer](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/critical-analysis.html) which monitors critical broker functions and emits WARN messages in some circumstances and can even stop the broker completely if the problem is critical enough. As noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/critical-analysis.html) you can tune how the critical analyzer functions. In your case you may want to increase `critical-analyzer-timeout` in `broker.xml`.

That said, you have **a lot** of data on disk. The broker is designed for data to *flow through* it. It is not meant to be a data repository like a relational database. The production and consumption of messages should be relatively balanced so that messages don't accumulate. The broker can certainly buffer messages if consumption falls behind for a bit, but eventually consumption must resume and catch up to eliminate any backlogs.